# RStudio: Stretched time series cross validation and using exponential smoothing models

Tags: time-series, forecasting, rstudio

[image]

I've been have trouble with a question for an assignment. I'm trying to apply an ETS model onto a stretch_tsibble in a time series cross validation. Running this either takes a long time to do or crashes my RStudio session. This is with one ETS model, my assignment requires three. I think there's a better solution to this and really need help with this.

My assignment involves using an ETS model on a training and test set then comparing it to a time series cross validation.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. As the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsibble/versions/0.9.1/topics/stretch_tsibble) says: *The output dimension will increase considerably with slide_tsibble() and stretch_tsibble(), which is likely to run out of memory when the data is large*. There's no magic: either you reduce the size of your data or you need more memory.